# Find the index of an element in a list

Tags: python

I am having an issue to find the index of each similar values within a list.

Example:

```
b = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"]
for x in b:
    if "a" in x:
        print(b.index(x))
```

my current results:

```
0
0
0
```

expected results:

```
0
2
3
```

(In my actual case we have two to 100 of similar values within a list so .index is not working well.)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Are you only interested in finding the indices of `"a"`?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to learn new methods and just in case I came across such issue in the future.

Comment: You may want to look up the built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerate`:

```
[n for n, i in enumerate(b) if i == 'a']
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem of algorithm. the method of **list.index(val)** returns the index of the **first** value to appear. If you want to find all indices of similar values, then you need to change your algorithm.

A common brute force approach for this is like:

```py
b = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"]
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] == 'a':
        print(i)
```

Which will probably output, as you have said:

```py
0
2
3
```

Comment: thank you this is what I want.

Comment: I will mark as answer in 6mins cool down

Comment: The method above is, as said, brute force. There are codes much better than that efficiency/time/memory wise.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straightforward:

```
def indices(arr, val):
    return [n for n, x in enumerate(arr) if x == val]

b = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"]

print(indices(b, "a"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code:

```
characters = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"]
for i in range(len(characters)):
    if characters[i] == "a":
        print(i)
```